# Test Google Adwords Server-to-server conversion tracking

Tags: google-ads-api

I am currently implementing server-to-server conversion tracking using this api: https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/api however I don't see any way to generate test ad clicks to test if it's working or not.. Does anyone know how to test this?